# Result of a while loop still happens even when the condition isn't met

Tags: javascript

I'm practising writing Javascript by making a Roguelike dungeon game but there is a problem when I want to create monsters. I have written a while loop such as:

```
this.getRandomCoordinatesInRoom = function(roomNumber) {
var validLocationFound = false;

while (!validLocationFound){
  // Generate co-ords in room first
  x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.roomList[roomNumber].width) + (this.roomList[roomNumber].posX));
  y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.roomList[roomNumber].height) + (this.roomList[roomNumber].posY));

  // Find location of (x,y) in Dungeon Array

  //alert(arrayLocation);
  var tmpX = ((this.roomList[roomNumber]).posX + x);
  var tmpY = ((this.roomList[roomNumber]).posY + y);
  var arrayLocation = ((tmpY * 80) + tmpX);
  //var arrayLocation = ((this.roomList[roomNumber].posX + x) + (80 * (this.roomList[roomNumber].posY + y)));
  if (this.dungeonArray[(tmpY + tmpX)] === "floor") {
    validLocationFound = true;
  };

  if ((x<this.roomList[roomNumber].posX) || (x>(this.roomList[roomNumber].posX + this.roomList[roomNumber].width))){
    alert("x out of bounds");
  };

  if ((y<this.roomList[roomNumber].posY) || (y>(this.roomList[roomNumber].posY + this.roomList[roomNumber].height))){
    alert("y out of bounds");
  };
  writeToScreen("Room upper left corner = " + (this.roomList[roomNumber].posX).toString() + "," + (this.roomList[roomNumber].posY).toString(),10);
  return [x,y];

  if (!(getTileAt(arrayLocation) === "floor")){
    alert("It messed up");
  }
};
```

The code randomly generates an x,y coordinate and converts it to a single number (My dungeon array is one dimensional, 0-79 across and then 80 is a new row). however, even when the code generates a coordinate that isn't valid (!= "floor"), it still finishes the function as though it returned true. Why is this?

Comment: Why are they all `if` conditions? no way you could make them `else if`?

Comment: Because you return [x,y], not matter what happend before (without a condition). So the loop runs only once until the return.

Comment: @WaKai: Looks like an answer to me...

Comment: `return` ends your loop.

Comment: I'm new to this so I'm just trying to get the basics working, that's why I haven't done     else if. And the x,y return write the co-ordinates to the right hand side of my screen to see if the co-ordinates are the same so I know if they have been duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `[x,y]` from inside the while loop. Declare the variables outside of the loop and then return the value from outside the loop. Or else, return is when `validLocationFound` is true.

```
var x, y ;
while(...) {
    ...
}
return [x, y];
```

Comment: Thanks, many people saying it's the return that's messing it up. Without the return it doesn't seem to run, so I'll look else where for the issue. Thanks very much all of you! :)

Comment: Edited the answer. Wording was very poor. You need to return from outside the loop.